# In generic type collection do we need to check getClass in overriden equal method?

Tags: java, generics

Generic collection, allows the same type of object, so while overriding equal method, do we need to use `getClass` for checking the same type of object.

My question is `(obj.getClass()!=this.getClass())` do we need this code in equal method of class which is used as Generic type in collection. 
We know that Generic type collection, we can only able **to add same type of object. So If I remove this code from equal method** then, will it give any problem.

New Overridden equal method in

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj==null){
           return false;
        }
        if(this == obj){
            return true;
        }
        Student std = (Student)obj;
        return name.equals(std.name) && rollNum == std.rollNum;
    }
```

My question is do we need the use getClass() in equal method if we are using this class in generic Collection, I think that line of code is not relevant, because generic will not allow to added different type of object

```
import java.util.*;
public class HashSetDemo {
    public static void main(String [] args){
            HashSet<Student> hashSet = new HashSet<Student>();
            hashSet.clear();
            Student std1 = new Student(11, "qaa");
            Student std2 = new Student(21, "aa");
            Student std3 = new Student(31, "saa");
            Student std4 = new Student(51, "aad");
            Student std5 = new Student(71, "aad");
            hashSet.add(std1);
            hashSet.add(std2);
            hashSet.add(std3);
            hashSet.add(std4);
            hashSet.add(std5);
    }
}

class Student{
    int rollNum;
    String name;
    public Student(int rollNum, String name){
        this.rollNum = rollNum;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //some code
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj){
            return true;
        }
        if(obj == null || (obj.getClass()!=this.getClass())){
            return false;
        }
        Student std = (Student)obj;
        return name.equals(std.name) && rollNum == std.rollNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a subclass of `Student` and you want instances of the subclass to be equal to instances of the baseclass, use `instanceof`. Otherwise, use `getClass()`, because it prevents you accidentally ending up with asymmetrical `equals` methods (e.g. [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#equals(java.lang.Object))). The fact that you're putting it in a generic collection is not really the issue.

Comment: If your question is "Should I check the type at all?" then yes, because the `equals` method should follow the normal contract of [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), which means that it will return false (not throw a `ClassCastException`) if you give it an object of some other type.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for comment, I removed the instanceof operator, now plz tell me the answer..

Comment: @khelwood plz see the updated question...

Comment: In any case, your line `if (obj==null && (obj.getClass()!=this.getClass()))` should say `if (obj==null || obj.getClass()!=this.getClass())` (OR not AND), otherwise you're inviting a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @khelwood that was miss place updated, My question is very straight, do w e need getClass in equal method, we we are using those object in Generic Collections..

Comment: And the answer is yes, you do need to check the class in your equals method. See comments above.

Answer (score 3):

`equals` must be reflexive, *symmetric*, transitive, consistent and return `false` for `null`.

The problem with `obj instanceof Student` is the symmetry. Assume you have some `MasterStudent extends Student` and follow the pattern "`instanceof CurrentClass`  and compare fields of CurrentClass" - just like it's implemented in Student. In this case you may easily get `student.equals(masterStudent) == true` and `masterStudent.equals(student) == false`.

You've edited your question and removed this part:

> Generic collection, allows the same type of object, so while overriding equal method, do we need to use instanceof or getClass for checking the subclass or same type of object.

Now you're basically just asking if you have to check the class in `equals` suggesting that the type will be guaranteed by the collection.

Short answer is *of course* you should check the class in `equals`. You should implement `equals` irrespective of possible usages.

Comment: I am not using instanceof operator, using only getClass then Plz provide answer...

Comment: @Guest Well, you have edited your question, which previously included *"Generic collection, allows the same type of object, so while overriding equal method, do we need to use instanceof or getClass for checking the subclass or same type of object."*.

Comment: Yes, because I was not getting the exact answer, Now I updated my question. My question is do we need the use geClass in equal method if we are using this class in generic Collection, I thing that  line of code is not relevant, because generic will not allow to added different type of object..

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with comments provided by Khelwood and also we are verifying with `&&` condition with null check it can be `||` because if `obj` is null then cause NullpointerException

```
if(obj == null || (obj.getClass()!=this.getClass())){
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: cool, so its better to use getClass() verification instead of `instanceof` to verify can you check as suggested by lexicore, `student.equals(masterStudent) == true and masterStudent.equals(student) == false`

Answer (score 0):

@khelwood is rigth. and in your code that "if" is wrong:

```
if(obj == null && (obj.getClass()!=this.getClass())){
        return false;
    }
```

what it will do: if obj is null you will get NPE at next obj.getClass(). null does not have a class. :-)

```
if (!(obj instanceof Student)) { return false;}
```

is enough. null is not an instance of any class.